# Pandas sort by group aggregate and column

Tags: python, sorting, group-by, dataframe, pandas

Given the following dataframe

```
In [31]: rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
         df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] * 2,
                            'B': rand.randn(6),
                            'C': rand.rand(6) > .5})

In [32]: df
Out[32]:      A         B      C
         0  foo  1.624345  False
         1  bar -0.611756   True
         2  baz -0.528172  False
         3  foo -1.072969   True
         4  bar  0.865408  False
         5  baz -2.301539   True
```

I would like to sort it in groups (`A`) by the aggregated sum of `B`, and then by the value in `C` (not aggregated). So basically get the order of the `A` groups with

```
In [28]: df.groupby('A').sum().sort('B')
Out[28]:             B  C
         A               
         baz -2.829710  1
         bar  0.253651  1
         foo  0.551377  1
```

And then by True/False, so that it ultimately looks like this:

```
In [30]: df.ix[[5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0]]
Out[30]: A         B      C
    5  baz -2.301539   True
    2  baz -0.528172  False
    1  bar -0.611756   True
    4  bar  0.865408  False
    3  foo -1.072969   True
    0  foo  1.624345  False
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Groupby A:

```
In [0]: grp = df.groupby('A')
```

Within each group, sum over B and broadcast the values using transform.  Then sort by B:

```
In [1]: grp[['B']].transform(sum).sort('B')
Out[1]:
          B
2 -2.829710
5 -2.829710
1  0.253651
4  0.253651
0  0.551377
3  0.551377
```

Index the original df by passing the index from above.  This will re-order the A values by the aggregate sum of the B values:

```
In [2]: sort1 = df.ix[grp[['B']].transform(sum).sort('B').index]

In [3]: sort1
Out[3]:
     A         B      C
2  baz -0.528172  False
5  baz -2.301539   True
1  bar -0.611756   True
4  bar  0.865408  False
0  foo  1.624345  False
3  foo -1.072969   True
```

Finally, sort the 'C' values within groups of 'A' using the `sort=False` option to preserve the A sort order from step 1:

```
In [4]: f = lambda x: x.sort('C', ascending=False)

In [5]: sort2 = sort1.groupby('A', sort=False).apply(f)

In [6]: sort2
Out[6]:
         A         B      C
A
baz 5  baz -2.301539   True
    2  baz -0.528172  False
bar 1  bar -0.611756   True
    4  bar  0.865408  False
foo 3  foo -1.072969   True
    0  foo  1.624345  False
```

Clean up the df index by using `reset_index` with `drop=True`:

```
In [7]: sort2.reset_index(0, drop=True)
Out[7]:
     A         B      C
5  baz -2.301539   True
2  baz -0.528172  False
1  bar -0.611756   True
4  bar  0.865408  False
3  foo -1.072969   True
0  foo  1.624345  False
```

Comment: Also, I assumed that `groupby`'s `sort=False` flag would return an arbitrary, not necessarily sorted order (I guess I was associating them with python dictionaries for some reason). But this answer implies that the flag is guaranteed to preserve the original order of the dataframe rows?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it preserves the order of the groups as they first appear .  I don't have any code to back this up, but some quick testing confirms this intuition.

Comment: Thanks @Zelazny7 for this answer. It is exactly what I want. However, it seems in the latest pandas package, to achieve the same `Out[7]`, `inplace=True` should be added to the arguments in `Input[7]` .

Comment: Adding more information:
sort() is now DEPRECATED. its is advisable to use DataFrame.sort_values()

Answer (score 29):

Here's a more concise approach...

```
df['a_bsum'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(sum)
df.sort(['a_bsum','C'], ascending=[True, False]).drop('a_bsum', axis=1)
```

The first line adds a column to the data frame with the groupwise sum. The second line performs the sort and then removes the extra column.

Result:

```
    A       B           C
5   baz     -2.301539   True
2   baz     -0.528172   False
1   bar     -0.611756   True
4   bar      0.865408   False
3   foo     -1.072969   True
0   foo      1.624345   False
```

NOTE: `sort` is deprecated, use `sort_values` instead

Comment: As with `sort_values` the last operation is not dropping the column. That is happening because the default is `inplace=False`. So, specifying `inplace=True` will also do the work. An alternative would be using the following  `df.drop('a_bsum', axis=1, inplace=True)` after.

Comment: Alternatively, assigning the dataframe to the variable `df` will do the work as well `df = df.sort_values(['a_bsum','C'], ascending=[True, False]).drop('a_bsum', axis=1)`.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this is to insert a dummy column with the sums in order to sort:

```
In [10]: sum_B_over_A = df.groupby('A').sum().B

In [11]: sum_B_over_A
Out[11]: 
A
bar    0.253652
baz   -2.829711
foo    0.551376
Name: B

in [12]: df['sum_B_over_A'] = df.A.apply(sum_B_over_A.get_value)

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
     A         B      C  sum_B_over_A
0  foo  1.624345  False      0.551376
1  bar -0.611756   True      0.253652
2  baz -0.528172  False     -2.829711
3  foo -1.072969   True      0.551376
4  bar  0.865408  False      0.253652
5  baz -2.301539   True     -2.829711

In [14]: df.sort(['sum_B_over_A', 'A', 'B'])
Out[14]: 
     A         B      C   sum_B_over_A
5  baz -2.301539   True      -2.829711
2  baz -0.528172  False      -2.829711
1  bar -0.611756   True       0.253652
4  bar  0.865408  False       0.253652
3  foo -1.072969   True       0.551376
0  foo  1.624345  False       0.551376
```

*and maybe you would drop the dummy row:*

```
In [15]: df.sort(['sum_B_over_A', 'A', 'B']).drop('sum_B_over_A', axis=1)
Out[15]: 
     A         B      C
5  baz -2.301539   True
2  baz -0.528172  False
1  bar -0.611756   True
4  bar  0.865408  False
3  foo -1.072969   True
0  foo  1.624345  False
```

Comment: I'm *sure* I've seen some clever way to do this here (essentially allowing a key to sort), but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Glad to know there's a better way to do `df.A.map(dict(zip(sum_B_over_A.index, sum_B_over_A)))` :) (should be `get_value`, no?). Also didn't know about column-wise drops, thanks a lot. (though I kinda prefer the version w/out the dummy column for some reason)

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV whoops typo :). Yes, it does seem silly using a dummy (tbh I could've been more clever with my apply [12] to do it in one, and it may well be more efficient, but I decided I wouldn't like to be the person reading it...). Like I say, I think there is a clever way to do this kind of comlex sort :s

Comment: You didn't sort by column C.

Comment: @MarkByers you can append 'C' to the list of columns to sort by, so it's: `df.sort(['sum_B_over_A', 'A', 'B', 'C'])`... I should really add link to the [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is difficult to understand.  However, group by A and sum by B then sort values descending.  The column A sort order depends on B.  You can then use filtering to create a new dataframe filter by A values order the dataframe.

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] * 2,
                        'B': rand.randn(6),
                        'C': rand.rand(6) > .5})
grouped=df.groupby('A')['B'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
print(grouped)
print(grouped.index.get_level_values(0))
```

Output:

```
A
foo    0.551377
bar    0.253651
baz   -2.829710
```