# How to sort a pandas dataFrame by two or more columns?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, sorting, data-analysis

Suppose I have a dataframe with columns `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to sort the dataframe by column `b` in ascending order, and by column `c` in descending order. How do I do this?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14946246/1948860

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas sort by group aggregate and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941366/pandas-sort-by-group-aggregate-and-column)

Answer (score 879, accepted):

As of the 0.17.0 release, the [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) method was deprecated in favor of [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).  `sort` was completely removed in the 0.20.0 release. The arguments (and results) remain the same:

```
df.sort_values(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False])
```

---

You can use the ascending argument of [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html):

```
df.sort(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False])
```

For example:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (10,2)), columns=['a','b'])

In [12]: df1.sort(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False])
Out[12]:
   a  b
2  1  4
7  1  3
1  1  2
3  1  2
4  3  2
6  4  4
0  4  3
9  4  3
5  4  1
8  4  1
```

---

As commented by @renadeen

> Sort isn't in place by default! So you should assign result of the sort method to a variable or add inplace=True to method call.

that is, if you want to reuse df1 as a sorted DataFrame:

```
df1 = df1.sort(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False])
```

or

```
df1.sort(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Sort isn't in place by default! So you should assign result of the `sort` method to a variable or add `inplace=True` to method call.

Comment: @renadeen very good point, I've updated by answer with that comment.

Comment: @Snoozer Yeah, I don't think sort's ever going to go away (mainly as it's used extensively in Wes' book), but there has been [some big changes in calling sort](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10726). Thanks! .. I really need to automate going through all my 1000s of pandas answers for deprecations!

Answer (score 85):

As of pandas 0.17.0, `DataFrame.sort()` is deprecated, and set to be removed in a future version of pandas. The way to sort a dataframe by its values is now is `DataFrame.sort_values`

As such, the answer to your question would now be

```
df.sort_values(['b', 'c'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 16):

For large dataframes of numeric data, you may see a significant performance improvement via [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html), which performs an indirect sort using a sequence of keys:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (10,2)), columns=['a','b'])
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*100000)

def pdsort(df1):
    return df1.sort_values(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False])

def lex(df1):
    arr = df1.values
    return pd.DataFrame(arr[np.lexsort((-arr[:, 1], arr[:, 0]))])

assert (pdsort(df1).values == lex(df1).values).all()

%timeit pdsort(df1)  # 193 ms per loop
%timeit lex(df1)     # 143 ms per loop
```

One peculiarity is that the defined sorting order with `numpy.lexsort` is reversed: `(-'b', 'a')` sorts by series `a` first. We negate series `b` to reflect we want this series in descending order.

Be aware that [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) only sorts with numeric values, while [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) works with either string or numeric values. Using `np.lexsort` with strings will give: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`.

Answer (score 0):

For those that come here for multi-column `DataFrame`, use `tuple with elements corresponding to each level`.

tuple with elements corresponding to each level:

```py
d = {}
d['first_level'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idx', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                                         data=[[10, 0.89, 0.98, 0.31],
                                               [20, 0.34, 0.78, 0.34]]).set_index('idx')
d['second_level'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idx', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                                          data=[[10, 0.29, 0.63, 0.99],
                                                [20, 0.23, 0.26, 0.98]]).set_index('idx')

df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)
df.sort_values(('second_level', 'b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort_values` has a stable sorting option which can be invoking by passing `kind='stable'`. Note that we need to reverse the columns to sort by to use the stable sorting correctly.

So the following two methods produce the same output, i.e. `df1` and `df2` are equivalent.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100,2)), columns=['a', 'b'])

df1 = df.sort_values(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False])  # sort by 'a' then 'b'

df2 = (
    df
    .sort_values('b', ascending=False)                     # sort by 'b' first
    .sort_values('a', ascending=True, kind='stable')       # then by 'a'
)

assert df1.eq(df2).all().all()
```

This is especially useful if you need a bit more involved sorting key.

Say, given `df` below, you want to sort by `'date'` and `'value'` but treat `'date'` like datetime values even though they are strings. A straightforward `sort_values` with two sort by columns would produce a wrong result; however, calling `sort_values` twice with the relevant sorting key would produce the correct output.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['10/1/2024', '10/1/2024', '2/23/2024'], 'value': [0, 1, 0]})

df1 = df.sort_values(['date', 'value'], ascending=[True, False])  # <--- wrong output

df2 = (
    df
    .sort_values('value', ascending=False)
    .sort_values('date', ascending=True, kind='stable', key=pd.to_datetime) 
)  # <--- correct output
```

N.B. We can get the same output by assigning a new datetime column and use it as a sort-by column but IMO, the stable sort with the sorting key is much cleaner.

```py
df3 = df.assign(dummy=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).sort_values(['dummy', 'value'], ascending=[True, False]).drop(columns='dummy')
```