# Splitting Dataframe with hierarchical index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, split

I have a large dataframe with hierarchical indexing (a simplistic/ format example provided in the code below). I would like to setup a loop/automated way of splitting the dataframe into subsets per unique index value, i.e. dfa, dfb, dfc etc. in the coded example below and store in a list.

I have tried the following but unfortunately to no success. Any help appreciated!

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(9), index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 
'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3]])

split = []
for value in data.index.unique():
    split.append(data[data.index == value])
```

Comment: Use `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(level=0)))`

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for but have you checked [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `pandas` function? The crucial part is that you can apply it across MultiIndex specifying which level of indexing (or what subset of levels) to group by. e.g.

```
split = {}
for value, split_group in data.groupby(level=0):
    split[value] = split_group
print(split)
```

as @jezrael points out a simpler way to do it is:

```
dict(tuple(df.groupby(level=0)))
```

Comment: apologies if not clear I would like to have separate dataframes splits such that dfa is a dataframe of all of the rows (3 rows) under index 'a' , and dfb is another dataframe of all the rows under index 'b' etc.

Comment: So you have it - I have changed the level to 0 and this is precisely what you get in the `split_group`s.

Comment: How do I access the dataframes in the list? if I type 'a' for example nothing is returned. The intention was to use this list of dataframes to run regressions over.

Comment: You can't use a list for that! I have changed the split to a dictionary which should give you what you need.

Comment: I'm still not able to access the data on the split dataframes, when I enter a to retrieve the first database it returns the error 'name 'a' is not defined'

Comment: Read a bit more about [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) and define what you mean by "database". I have no idea what you are doing to get the error.