# I have a worksheet of multiple sheets and i want each of them to be get assigned as individual dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

Example :-

Example_workbook has 20 sheets.
I want each of them to get assign as individual dataframe in python.I have tried 
as below but this would be only helpful to get single sheet at a time.
Do anyone know how can we use "**Def**" function to iterate through sheets and assign each of them as new dataframe.

e.g

```
df = pd.read_excel("practice1.xlsx",sheet_name=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read_excel` method reads all the sheets at once if you set the `sheet_name` kwarg to be `None`.

```
sheets = pd.read_excel("practice1.xlsx",sheet_name=None)  # this is a dict
for sheet_name, df in sheets.items():
    "calculations on the dataframe df"
```

you can read more info about the `sheet_name` kwarg [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out - you'll get a dictionary of DataFrames, from which you can access each of the dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
d={}    
sheets = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'aaa', 'bbb']

for sheet in sheets:
    d[sheet] = pd.read_excel('practice1.xlsx', sheetname=sheet)
```

Here's the link to the resource:

[Create multiple dataframes in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop)

Edit: the answer above is actually better, as you don't have to specify sheet names. 'Sheet_name' didn't work for me, so I came up with this solution and only after I realized that typing 'sheetname' (without '_') does the trick for me.