# Create different dataframe from one given condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I want to create a dataframe for each type of COD_VARIABLE, for instance I want a dataframe called 179(doesnt matter the name ofc) with all the rows that have 179 on COD_VARIABLE, and so on with the other values of COD_VARIABLE.

I know how to do it one by one but would be useful to know how to make a function of for loop that does it.

I checked this but it doesnt help me:
[Create multiple dataframes in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop)

Comment: Filter/Subset the dataframe on unique rows of COD_Variable

Comment: Finally did it:

unique_codvariable = empresas.COD_VARIABLE.unique()


dfs_codvariable = {'df_{}'.format(r): empresas[empresas.COD_VARIABLE == r] for r in unique_codvariable}