# How to iterate through pandas-datareader and create multiple dataframes for each stock ticker?

Tags: python, dataframe, sqldatareader, stock, stocks

I want to iteratively create multiple dataframes from a list of ticker names.

Here is the stack overflow post i'm referencing:

[Stack Overflow Post - Iteratively Create Multiple Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop/30638956)

I'm having trouble understanding how to accomplish this, i feel like i'm missing or misunderstanding something here?

I wrote up the following list and dictionary

```
list_of_tickers = ['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC']
dict_of_tickers = {name: pd.DataFrame() for name in list_of_tickers}
```

However when i run this portion of the code i get the following error:

```
for ticker, ticker_data in dict_of_tickers.items():
    ticker_data = data.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)
```

This creates one single dataframe of all tickers but doesn't allow me to distinguish between them, i feel like i'm missing some key logic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the DataReader iterates over the list itself so the need to create a dictionary to iterate isn't necessary.

The following lines of code achieve what I was seeking which is an alternative to concatenating multiple dataframes from each stock ticker to avoid specifying DataReader for each symbol.

> 1. Sets the date ranges:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2006,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
```

> 2. Specifies the symbols:

```
 list_of_tickers = ['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC']
```

> 3. Iterates over each ticker, creates a single multilevel column dataframe:

```
p = data.DataReader(list_of_tickers, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

> 4. **OPTIONAL:** Then pivot the 'symbols' column level and replaces the Date index so it can be used in analysis:

```
res = p.stack().reset_index()
```

> 5. **OPTIONAL:** This step isn't necessary and was purely for aesthetics to clean up the FrozenList and index names:

```
res.columns.names=[None]
res.index.names = ['ID']
```

Answer (score 1):

`ticker_data` is just a variable that's created and overwritten each iteration of your `for` loop. That doesn't help. To update your dictionary, assign a value to a key explicitly:

```
for ticker in dict_of_tickers:
    dict_of_tickers['ticker'] = data.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

This assumes `data.DataReader` returns a dataframe. Notice we iterate keys, as the value (an empty dataframe) is not required for this assignment. In fact, you don't *need* to define a dictionary with empty dataframe values in the first place. Just use a single dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_of_tickers = {ticker: data.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end) \
                   for ticker in list_of_tickers}
```

Comment: Thank you i learned a great deal from your response, it appears however that for some reason DataReader returns as a dataframe when called by itself outside of the dictionary comprehension but when used as the value for the dictionary it returns a single column array value. Is there a way to extract the values  as dataframes?

Comment: @Lee, No, I can't replicate. `data.DataReader` *can't* do "something different" within a dictionary comprehension versus outside. It's doing the same thing both times, but you should try and find out what (hint: `print(type(data.DataReader(...))` in your `for` loop).

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your help!