# Importing column as list to column header variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that goes like this

```
AAPL, TSCO, ASDA, ....
10, 11, 12, ...
9, 10, 11, ...
...,...,...,...
```

Now is there a way to import a list all of these as variables of their column header. So it will be`AAPL = [ 10, 9, ...,...]`

I know how to print out a list of column headers using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', index_col=0)

col_headers = list(df.columns)
```

So now I can loop over this list, but is there a way, to automatically assign the variable name as the list header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best here is create dictonary of list and for each list select by key - here by columns name:

```
d = df.to_dict('list')
print (d)
{'AAPL': [10, 9], 'TSCO': [11, 10], 'ASDA': [12, 11]}

print (d['AAPL'])
[10, 9]

print (type(d['AAPL']))
<class 'list'>
```

What you need is possible, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956):

```
for c in df.columns:
    globals()[c] =  df[c].tolist()

print (AAPL)
[10, 9]
```

Comment: And I will be able to chage this list? i.e. size, list variables ect? As long as ts kept as a list?

Comment: @SamHarper - If use `d['AAPL']` is is list, use it instead `AAPL` like you mentoned in question.

Comment: @SamHarper what do you mean by " will be able to chage this list? i.e. size, list variables ect?"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require `pandas`.

```py
import csv

class MyTable:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            self.data = [row for row in reader]

    def column(self, key, cast_as = str):
        return sorted([
                cast_as(value[key]) 
                for value in self.data
            ])

# usage:
>>> dataset = MyTable("foo.csv")
>>> aapl = dataset.column('AAPL', float)
>>> print(aapl)
[10., 9.]
```