# Assign dict key as dataframe name and value as dataframe itself

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have one dictionary of several pandas dataframes. It looks like this:

```
key  Value
A    pandas dataframe here
B    pandas dataframe here
C    pandas dataframe here
```

I need to extract dataframes from dict as a separate part and assign dict key as a name.

Desired output should be as many separate dataframes as many values of my dict have.

```
A = dict.values() - this is first dataframe

B = dict.values() - this is second dataframe
```

Note that dataframes names are dict keys.

I tried this code but without any success.

```
for key, value in my_dict_name.items():
    key = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(value)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really following, you say you have a dictionary of pandas dataframes. But it is unclear to me what te expected output should be. "Unpacking" a dictionary in variable names is really not a good idea at all (it is a severe anti-pattern). Since you basically never know what variables you will (re)define.

Comment: I have dictionary of dataframes. Values of dict are valid pandas dataframes and I need to unpack and assign dict keys as dataframe names.

Comment: @NodarOkroshiashvilli: but now imagine that there is a key with the name `'list'`, `dict'`, etc. This will override the `list`, `dict`, ... builtin, and will therefore likely eventually crash the rest of your program.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand your point and also I see why it can be an anti-pattern. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Why unpack them? They are far more accessible if you just leave them alone inside that dict...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible:

Thanks @ Willem Van Onsem for better explanation:

> It is a quite severe anti-pattern, especially since it can override existing variables, and one can never exclude that scenario

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'b':['b']})
c = pd.DataFrame({'c':['c']})

d = {'A':a, 'B':b, 'C':c}
print (d)
{'A':    a
0  a, 'B':    b
0  b, 'C':    c
0  c}

for k, v in d.items():
    globals()[k] =  v

print (A)
   a
0  a
```

I think here the best is `MultiIndex` if same columns or index values in each `DataFrame`, also dictionary of DataFrame is perfectly OK.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to stress the "not recommended" a bit. It is a quite severe anti-pattern, especially since it can override existing variables, and one can never exclude that scenario :)

Comment: I'm not as an experienced programmer as you are here guys but, I'll try my best. Until that @jezrael's solution works perfectly