# month or specified date-range wise grouping

Tags: python, pandas, date

Want to group my data by month-wise or specified date-range. Have nearly 3 months of data with non-unique dates (YYYY-MM-DD), already in pandas 'date' format, like

```
Col1 Col2 Date       Val 
12   23   2018-11-20  4
13   78   2018-09-21  4
14   82   2018-10-28  5
15   22   2018-11-10  8
17   35   2018-10-23  9
```

Want to separate them in Nov(11), Oct(10), Sept(09) wise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the best is create dictionary:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)))
print (d)
{9:    Col1  Col2       Date  Val
1    13    78 2018-09-21    4, 10:    Col1  Col2       Date  Val
2    14    82 2018-10-28    5
4    17    35 2018-10-23    9, 11:    Col1  Col2       Date  Val
0    12    23 2018-11-20    4
3    15    22 2018-11-10    8}

print (d[9])
   Col1  Col2       Date  Val
1    13    78 2018-09-21    4
```

Or:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b'))))
print (d)
{'Nov':    Col1  Col2       Date  Val
0    12    23 2018-11-20    4
3    15    22 2018-11-10    8, 'Oct':    Col1  Col2       Date  Val
2    14    82 2018-10-28    5
4    17    35 2018-10-23    9, 'Sep':    Col1  Col2       Date  Val
1    13    78 2018-09-21    4}

print (d['Nov'])
   Col1  Col2       Date  Val
0    12    23 2018-11-20    4
3    15    22 2018-11-10    8
```

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible create DataFrames by groups:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')):
    globals()['df_' + str(i)] =  g

print (df_Nov)
   Col1  Col2       Date  Val
0    12    23 2018-11-20    4
3    15    22 2018-11-10    8
```

---

If need aggregate by months:

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month).sum()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. My explanation was may not be good. I just want to split the dataframe into parts, say 'df_nov', 'df_oct', 'df_sept' from the main dataframe. The one you have suggested summing up the values of all the other columns with respect to these three months (which might be useful later on).

Comment: Tried the 1st one. Perfect! Thank you so much. Will be very handy in various cases also.