# Convert pandas df to dict of list

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

here
I want to convert a dataframe to dict of list.

Here's my dataframe

```
    day     session     sales
0   Friday  Early Morning   11105.50
1   Friday  Evening     8168.00
2   Friday  Late Night  1450.00
3   Friday  Morning     14802.00
4   Friday  Night   2925.00
5   Friday  Noon    10276.25
6   Monday  Early Morning   9553.75
7   Monday  Evening     11431.00
```

and here's what i want it to be like, for each and every day and session

```
monday = {
        "name": "Monday",
        "data": [
            {
                "x": "Morning",
                "y": 18014.00
            }, 
            {
                "x": 'Night',
                "y": 2353.50
            }, 

            }
        ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `df.to_dict()` will get you started

Comment: @jezrael sorry for that, I've made changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to [create dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop/30638956#30638956) for all days for possible select by `key`s:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'session':'x', 'sales':'y'})
df1 = df.groupby('day')['x','y'].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='data')
print (df1)
      day                                               data
0  Friday  [{'x': 'Early Morning', 'y': 11105.5}, {'x': '...
1  Monday  [{'x': 'Early Morning', 'y': 9553.75}, {'x': '...

d = {k:v.to_dict('r') for k, v in df1.groupby('day')}
#print (d)

print (d['Monday'])
[{'day': 'Monday', 'data': [{'x': 'Early Morning', 'y': 9553.75}, 
                            {'x': 'Evening', 'y': 11431.0}]}]
```

Comment: You're a savior @jezrael!

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.iloc[:,1:].set_axis(["x","y"],axis=1).to_dict("record")

df1.groupby('day').apply(function1).reset_index().set_axis(["name","data"],axis=1).to_dict("record")
```

output is

```
[{'name': 'Friday',
  'data': [{'x': 'Early Morning', 'y': 11105.5},
   {'x': 'Evening', 'y': 8168.0},
   {'x': 'Late Night', 'y': 1450.0},
   {'x': 'Morning', 'y': 14802.0},
   {'x': 'Night', 'y': 2925.0},
   {'x': 'Noon', 'y': 10276.25}]},
 {'name': 'Monday',
  'data': [{'x': 'Early Morning', 'y': 9553.75},
   {'x': 'Evening', 'y': 11431.0}]}]
```