# Create new Series variable for each column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scope

Given a `DataFrame`, I'd like to run code that creates a new variable for each column, with the same name as the column.

For example, given this `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nums': [1, 2], 'strings': ['a', 'b']})
```

I want code that produces two `Series` variables: `nums` (`[1, 2]`) and `strings` (['a', 'b']`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible also by another solution:

```
for i in df.columns:
    globals()[i] =  df[i]
print (nums)
0    1
1    2
Name: nums, dtype: int64
```

So better is create dictionary of `Series` by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='series'` and select by `key`s:

```
d = df.to_dict('series')
print(d['nums'])

0    1
1    2
Name: nums, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in df.columns:
    exec(i + " = df['" + i + "']")
```

Running a function may be possible to pass any `DataFrame`, but I hit scoping issues.