# Creating multiple pandas dataframes from a dictionary which has stock datafor a list of companies

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me understand how can a create multiple pandas dataframes like
df1
df2
...
df100.
I have a dictionary, like below and would like to iterate through each key to create a new dataframe.

[image]

and each key has data like below:

[image]

Comment: What is reason for it? It is not recommended - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop/30638956#30638956)

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure what I am going to do with it, I can perform pretty much all my analysis from the dictionary itself. However, while exploring a few things online, I ended up having this question in mind. So for now, its mostly for improving my python knowledge just for knowing how would it be done.

Comment: yop, I think my comment it is not necessary, dictionary of DataFrames is good. Only if need one big DataFrame then use `df = pd.concat(frames)`

Comment: But still, would there be a way? and why is it not recommended? I am guessing for memory and processing reasons?

Comment: check link in first comment ;)

Comment: Ah, ok. Got it. Thanks.