# create dictionaries for combination of columns of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

If I have 100 columns in a dataframe and I want to create dictionaries of pair of columns, the key would always be a fixed columns. How can it be done?

Let's say we have a dataframe like this:

```
k    v1    v2    ...    v99
============================
i    1     2     ...    9
ii   11    22    ...    99
iii  111   222   ...    999
...
```

I would want dictionaries `dict_v1`, `dict_v2` ... `dict_v99`. For example `dict_v2` would be:

```
{'i': 2, 'ii': 22, 'iii': 222, ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest create dictionary of dictionaries like:

```
d = df.set_index('k').to_dict()
print (d)
{'v1': {'i': 1, 'ii': 11, 'iii': 111}, 
 'v2': {'i': 2, 'ii': 22, 'iii': 222}, 
 'v99': {'i': 9, 'ii': 99, 'iii': 999}}
```

Then each dict is possible select by key:

```
print (d['v2'])
{'i': 2, 'ii': 22, 'iii': 222}
```

Another idea should be:

```
df1 = df.set_index('k')
print (df1)
      v1   v2  v99
k                 
i      1    2    9
ii    11   22   99
iii  111  222  999

print (df1['v2'].to_dict())
{'i': 2, 'ii': 22, 'iii': 222}
```

What you need is possible, but is [bad idea to add names dynamically to a Python namespace.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956/2901002):

```
for k, v in df.set_index('k').to_dict().items():
    globals()[f'dict_{k}'] =  v

print (dict_v2)
{'i': 2, 'ii': 22, 'iii': 222}
```