# Reading multiple files in the same folder to different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few csv files in same folder an I need to add them to different dataframes of the same name. I am using the below code

```
for file in files:
file_name = file.split('.')
if file_name[1] == 'csv':
    file_name[0] = pd.read_csv(file)
else:
    continue
```

The list of files is ['',
 'bond_ratings',
 'fund_allocations',
 'fund_config',
 'fund_ratios',
 'fund_specs',
 'Hack',
 'other_specs',
 'return_10year',
 'return_3year',
 'return_5year']

However, when I try say 'bond_ratings.head()' it says bind_ratings is not defined. Where am I wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dict of DataFrames:

```
d = {}
for file in files:
    file_name = file.split('.')
    if file_name[1] == 'csv':
        d[file_name[0]] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

And then select by keys:

```
print (d['bond_ratings'])
```

---

What you need is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible:

```
for file in files:
    file_name = file.split('.')
    if file_name[1] == 'csv':
        globals()[file_name[0]] = pd.read_csv(file)

print (bond_ratings)
```