# Create different dataframes for different datasets stored in a folder

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to create a dataframe for each of the following datasets (csv files stored a folder):

```
0 text1.csv
1 text2.csv
2 text3.csv
3 text4.csv
4 text5.csv
```

The above list is created using `os.chdir` and lists all the csv files included in a folder in the following path:

```
os.chdir("path")
```

To create the dataframe (to be used later on) for each of the datasets above, I am doing as follow:

```
texts=[]

for item in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    texts.append(item)

for (x,z) in enumerate(texts):
    print(x,z)
    df = pd.read_csv(datasets[int(x)])
    df.index.name = datasets[int(x)]
```

However, it does not create any dataframe. I think the problem is in `df`, as I am not distinguishing it for each dataset (but I am only trying to read each dataset using `pd.read.csv(datasets[int(x)])`).

Could you please tell me how to create a dataframe per each of the datasets (for example `df1` related to `text1`, `df2` related to `text2`, and so on)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are happy with a ```dict``` of dataframes, which you will have to use keys to access each one later, then @holdenweb's answer to this SO question is a good one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a list of dataframes what you are looking for?

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

results=[]

paths =  glob.glob("*.csv"):

for path in paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    results.append(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a function and return a list of the dataframes

Simple, one-liner function:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


def get_all_csv(path, sep=','):
    # read all the csv files in a directory to a list of dataframes
    return [pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=sep)
            for csv_file in glob.glob(path + "*.csv")]

# get all the csv in the current directory
dfs = get_all_csv('./', sep=';')
print(dfs)
```

Comment: your file must have strange format, I updated it to use the `;` tokenization. The original script should work with a normal csv though

Comment: unfortunately it is still not working. It is still returning me the following error: `ParserError: Expected 1 fields in line 51, saw 7`.  So I think both cases should be included (original + the updated answer)

Comment: I updated it to let you choose the sep as a function argument. I would check your csv though and make sure all the rows have the same amount of columns

Comment: It seems like your csv has 1 column but one row has 7 commas (probably because of commas `,` in the row, wrap the row in `"` to get around this)

Comment: Yes, I think so. Unfortunately it is still not working because of that error. I think the other way to fix it is to add a try/except condition in order to get around it. But I have not been able to add it in your code. Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: my pleasure! You would have to use a traditional `for` loop instead of a comprehension to use try/except otherwise it wouldn't return anything