# How to create multiple empty pd.DataFrame which are named like values from List

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to create multiple empty pd.DataFrame and I thought I can do it with a loop like this:

```
for share in tickers:
    share=pd.DataFrame()
```

with:

```
tickers=['AAPL', 'MSFT', '^GSPC', 'VNA.DE', '^GDAXI', 'HJUE.HA', 'GYC.DE', '2B7K.DE']
```

But this creates a empty DataFrame named "share" and not 8 different Dataframe named like AAPL, MSFT,...

Answer (score 1):

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), better is create dictionary of `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = {x: pd.DataFrame() for x in tickers}
```

---

```
print (dfs)
{'AAPL': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 'MSFT': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], '^GSPC': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 'VNA.DE': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], '^GDAXI': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 'HJUE.HA': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 'GYC.DE': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], '2B7K.DE': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []}
```

And then select by keys:

```
print (dfs['AAPL'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: @Ch3steR - hmm, I try `dfs['AAPL'] = dfs['AAPL'].assign(a= 1)` and not changed all DataFrames, how do you think inplace change?

Comment: No problem. `defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)` is another alternative.+1

Comment: but if I try to fill the DataFrames with different content for example with ```shares[tickers[0]]['Adj Close']=hist_data['Adj Close_AAPL']``` all DataFrames in this dict will be filled with the data. not just the first one