# Create bins based on breakpoints array

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel files with four sheets (2016_data, 2017_data, 2018_data and 2019_data). Column C of all these sheets is the weight of a product.
I want to use an array such as below that includes the bin breakpoints.
breakpoints_1=[1, 300, 1000]

NOTE: The break points array size is not known. Sometimes it could have 10 points, and sometimes just 2 points. (Example: breakpoints_2= [1, 4, 7, 523,650, 1700]

Now I want to classify the data of each of above sheets based on the above array.

If we use breakpoints_1, then the results will be:

```
2016_data_1=df_2016[(df_2016["weight"]>=1) & (df_2016["weight"]<300)]
2016_data_2=df_2016[(df_2016["weight"]>=300) & (df_2016["weight"]<1000)]

2017_data_1=df_2017[(df_2017["weight"]>=1) & (df_2017["weight"]<300)]
2017_data_2=df_2017[(df_2017["weight"]>=300) & (df_2017["weight"]<1000)]

2018_data_1=df_2018[(df_2018["weight"]>=1) & (df_2018["weight"]<300)]
2018_data_2=df_2018[(df_2018["weight"]>=300) & (df_2018["weight"]<1000)]

2019_data_1=df_2019[(df_2019["weight"]>=1) & (df_2019["weight"]<300)]
2019_data_2=df_2019[(df_2019["weight"]>=300) & (df_2019["weight"]<1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to have so many dataframes ? I would suggest you to add a column for the category you want to assign them.

Let's use a sample dataframe and see how it works:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'weight': np.random.randint(0, 1500, 150)})
```

This piece of code will return you 'A' if weight is between 1 and 300, 'B' if between 300 and 1000, else 'C'. The `bins` argument contains your binning values, `right` is set to False so that the interval exclude the right bound, and `labels` contains your labels after applying pandas.cut

```py
pd.cut(df.weight, bins=[1, 300, 1000, np.inf], right=False, labels=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

```py
    weight
0   A
1   B
2   A
3   B
4   B
```

So if you add a weight_category column, you could do conditional computations later on.

```py
df['weight_category'] = pd.cut(df.weight, 
                         bins=[1, 300, 1000, np.inf], 
                         right=False, 
                         labels=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df
    weight  weight_category
0   1404    C
1   885     B
2   612     B
3   90      A
4   1092    C
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need multiple dataframes.

Comment: Then you can combine the solution above with a loop as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop). You will have to filter based on the assigned category to create your several dataframes