# Call DataFrame named using for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a several of dataframes from a larger dataframe using a for loop and dataframe conditions. Here is a snippet of the code below provided df is declared

```
D_1 = []
for l in range(0,B):
    globals()["Final_df_" + str(l)] = df[df.index % B == l].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I am not sure exactly how to call them for further computations using a loop again. I have tried different ways

```
     D_1 = ["Final_df_" +str(l)].loc[:,1]        #try1
     D_1.append(["Final_df_" + str(l)].loc[:,1]) #try2
```

But I get an error

> 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

I am pretty sure it is because of the square parenthesis after str(l) but I am not sure how to call them with out the brackets as `D_1 = "Final_df_" + str(l).loc[:,1]` shows an error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

I even tried declaring D_1 as a dataframe but still shows error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using [globals for string variables is not good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop/30638956#30638956), better is create dictionary:

```
dfs = {}
for l in range(0,B):
    dfs["Final_df_" + str(l)] = df[df.index % B == l].reset_index(drop=True)
```

And then call like:

```
l = 1
print (dfs["Final_df_" + str(l)])
```

---

But if really need it:

```
l = 1
globals()["Final_df_" + str(l)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the global(). But I am stuck on calling the dataframe {in this case "Final_df_" + str(l)} using the for loop to perform computations like the one mentioned above (["Final_df_" + str(l)].loc[:,1]).

Comment: @AjithViswanath - Hmm, so you need `globals()["Final_df_" + str(l)] = globals()["Final_df_" + str(l)].loc[:, 1]` ?

Comment: Yes. After creating the dataframe 'Final_df_0' (first instance), i want to perform computations on some of the data.

Comment: @AjithViswanath - so working for you comment above?

Comment: I am able to create the dataframe using the first coding snippet. But I am not sure how to call them to perform computations and store them in D_1. I tried the codes in the second snippet but i get error messages

Comment: @AjithViswanath - What is error? I test it and working nice (if need select column `1`).

Comment: @AjithViswanath - Or you need select second column? then use `iloc` like `globals()["Final_df_" + str(l)] = globals()["Final_df_" + str(l)].iloc[:, 1]`

Comment: I tried your code and it works great. The mistake I made was that I did not access the dataframe (Final_df_0) as a global dataframe.
 Thank you very much for the clarification!