# Loop which creates dataframe from each column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe of 100+ columns and would like to turn each column into it's own dataframe with the same index of Date.

eg;

Original Dataframe;

```
Date     A B C D E F G H
01/01/12 3 8 9 2 9 3 3 2
02/01/12 7 8 7 7 3 2 0 3
.
.
.
.
31/01/19 8 2 9 3 2 7 2 0
```

End Goal;

Dataframe A;

```
Date     A
01/01/12 3
02/01/12 7
.
.
.
.
31/01/12 8
```

Dataframe B

```
Date     B
01/01/12 8
02/01/12 8
.
.
.
.
31/01/19 2
```

and so on for each other columns..

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want DataFrame called `A,B,C` by columns names is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), better is create dictionary:

```
d = {c: df[[c]] for c in df.columns}
print (d)

print (d['A'])
          A
Date       
01/01/12  3
02/01/12  7
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! I want to use the groupby function afterwards so was hoping to be able to manipulate a dataframe.

Comment: @spcol - you get dictionary of DataFrames, so instead `df1, df2` use `d['A'], d['B']` and working same  way.