# Creating variable number of lists from pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe being generated by some other piece of code - the dataframe may have different number of columns each time it is generated: let's call them `col1,col2,...,coln` where n is not fixed. Please note that col1,col2,... are just placeholders, the actual names of columns can be arbitrary like TimeStamp or PrevState.

From this, I want to convert each column into a list, with the name of the list being the same as the column. So, I want a list named `col1` with the entries in the first column of the dataframe and so on till `coln`.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: post the sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables, use *a container*. List another list, or in this case, a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), better is create dictionary:

```
d = df.to_dict('list')
```

And then select list by keys of dict from columns names:

```
print (d['col'])
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
        'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
        'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
})

d = df.to_dict('list')
print (d)
{'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'B': [4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4], 'C': [7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 3]}

print (d['A'])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: explicit is better than implicit, use `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - ya, btw, reopened, because part dupe.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df["colTWO"] = [6,7,8,9,10]

for col_name in df.columns:
    exec(col_name + " = " + df[col_name].values.__repr__())
```