# Generate daily periodic interval dataframes from a large time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have 31-day time series dataset which I extract using the below query.

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv

conn = pymysql.connect(host='',user='',password='',db='',port='',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

dbquery = """SELECT * FROM 'table_name' where 'date' between ('2012-03-01 00:00:00') and ('2012-03-31 23:59:59') """

df = pd.read_sql_query(dbquery, conn)
df.to_csv('one_month_timeseries_data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

The extracted dataframe is structured as below.

```
id date                  value
1  2012-01-01 00:00:00   33
5  2012-01-02 00:00:01   15
.
.
.
.
2  2012-01-30 23:59:58   10
5  2012-01-31 23:59:59   5
```

I want to further loop through each day (00:00:00 - 23:59:59) through the entire dataset and split the dataframe into 3 separate dataframes of 8 hour intervals each grouped into **sleep** (00:00:00 - 07:59:59), **work** (08:00:00 - 15:59:59), **home** (16:00:00 - 23:59:59).

**Expected output**:

e.g., for day 1:

day1_df_sleep:

```
id date                  value
1  2012-01-01 00:00:00   33
.
.
.
.
3  2012-01-01 07:59:59   10
```

day1_df_work:

```
id date                   value
1  2012-01-01 08:00:00    12
.
.
.
.
4  2012-01-01 15:59:59    50
```

day1_df_home:

```
id date                   value
1  2012-01-01 16:00:00    12
.
.
.
.
4  2012-01-01 23:59:59    50
```

etc..until day 31

I have read about pandas' date_range() function but I am not sure how best to implement it where I only have the date column.

How best can I implement this using pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `dt.day` and `dt.hour` and create new dataframes by filtering by the different days and different times of the day. You cannot use `between()` as an alternative to `.lt` and `.ge`, because the lowerbound is inclusive while the upper bound is exclusive in your desired output. As a separate problem, you can loop through each day, and below is what you would do for each day, and you could set a variable for day when looping through. Looping through each day and creating dataframes for each day is obviously going to be a little bit more complicated.

I don't know the reason for creating separated dataframes by day, but why not just have a function with a varaible for day to return output, which you could call with a parameter for user input, writing it back to sql or excel, etc. without having to create separate dataframes.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
day1_df_sleep = df[df['date'].dt.day == 1 & df['date'].dt.hour.ge(0) & df['date'].dt.hour.lt(8)]
day1_df_work = df[df['date'].dt.day == 1 & df['date'].dt.hour.ge(8) & df['date'].dt.hour.lt(16)]
day1_df_home = df[df['date'].dt.day == 1 & df['date'].dt.hour.ge(16) & df['date'].dt.hour.lt(24)]
```

For example you could do something like this to loop:

```
df = d.copy()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
for i in range(1,31):
    day1_df_sleep = df[df['date'].dt.day == i & df['date'].dt.hour.ge(0) & df['date'].dt.hour.lt(8)]
    day1_df_work = df[df['date'].dt.day == i & df['date'].dt.hour.ge(8) & df['date'].dt.hour.lt(16)]
    day1_df_home = df[df['date'].dt.day == i & df['date'].dt.hour.ge(16) & df['date'].dt.hour.lt(24)]
    print(day1_df_sleep, day1_df_work, day1_df_home)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David. It works partially. The problem is that it only keeps looping through the records for day 1 and does not continue to process the rest of the 30 days.

Comment: No problem @Gee it's a tougher solution to get the different dataframes. I know that there is a use case for many different dataframes, but I would envision a function with parameters that you could run in a for loop rather than all of the dataframes. Please check out the second answer with more votes here as well as the last answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop

Comment: Thanks, and by the way the reason for creating separate dataframes is to compute several features per each interval of the day namely sleep, work, and home.

Comment: If use the **groupby** function, I get back the grouped dataframes for each of the 31 days;

`df_grouped = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.date])`

`for j, df_group in df_grouped:`
    `print (df_group)`

But the challenge still remains on how to apply the for-loop that you suggested on each of the daily groups **(df_group)** in order to extract each day's dataframe intervals: sleep, work, and home.