# create multiple dataframes with python

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I have a list filepath with the ubication of the files I need to read (115 files), I need to read those files and add columns header (same for all files), also I have a list with the files names I want to use but no idea in how make it.

filepath look like this

```
['drive/My Drive/forex/DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2015.csv',
 'drive/My Drive/forex/DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2016.csv',
 'drive/My Drive/forex/DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2017.csv',
 'drive/My Drive/forex/DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2018.csv',
 'drive/My Drive/forex/DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2019.csv']
```

filename is like this

```
['DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2015',
 'DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2016',
 'DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2017',
 'DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2018',
 'DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2019']
```

and I was adding the columns header like this

```
DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2015= pd.read_csv("drive/My Drive/forex/DAT_MT_BCOUSD_M1_2015.csv",
                                    names=["Date","Time","Bar OPEN Bid Quote","Bar HIGH Bid Quote","Bar 
                                    LOW Bid Quote","Bar CLOSE Bid Quote","Volume"])
```

any ideas on how aproach the problem?

Comment: Does this help ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you create a Python dictionary with the dataframes inside, and access them using their filenames as the dictionary keys.

```
new_dict = {filename: pd.read_csv("drive/My Drive/forex/{}.csv".format(filename),
                                  names=["Date","Time","Bar OPEN Bid Quote",
                                         "Bar HIGH Bid Quote","Bar LOW Bid Quote",
                                         "Bar CLOSE Bid Quote","Volume"]) \
            for filename in filename_list}
```