# Splitting Dataframe into different group by product

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split my Dataframe such that each Dataframe is for a product. Given below is how my Dataframe looks like:

```
row_label, jan, feb, mar, apr
prod_a, 100, 120, 123, 150
prod_b, 123, 233, 200, 40
prod_c, 10, 23, 34, 33
```

Expected output:

Dataframe for `prod_a`

```
row_label, value
jan, 100
feb, 120
mar, 123
apr, 150
```

Dataframe for `prod_b`

```
row_label, value
jan, 123
feb, 233
mar, 200
apr, 40
```

Dataframe for `prod_c`

```
row_label, value
jan, 10
feb, 23
mar, 34
apr, 33
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest here create dictionary of DataFrames in dictionary comprehension:

```
df1 = df.set_index('row_label').T

dfs = {x: df1[x].to_frame(name='value') for x in df1.columns}

print (dfs['prod_a'])
```

Variables from strings are not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible, e.g. with `globals`:

```
for x in df1.columns:
    globals()[x] =  df1[x].to_frame('value')

print (prod_a)
```

Another idea with `groupby`, thank you @Lunalo John for idea:

```
dfs = {k: v.T for k,  v in df.set_index('row_label').groupby('row_label')}
print (dfs['prod_a'])
row_label  prod_a
jan           100
feb           120
mar           123
apr           150
```

Comment: You can also store them in a list  `[df_val for df, df_val in df.groupby("row_label")]`

Comment: @jezrael thanks for this, I am able to get the dict as expected. However when I try to consolidate this dict to a master Dataframe I get `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: @jezrael, I did `pd.DataFrame(dfs)`

Comment: @KevinNash - I suggest use `pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)`

Comment: @KevinNash - and if need consolidate better is change `.to_frame('value')` to `.to_frame()` for avoid duplicated columns names