# Pandas: Create different dataframes from an unique multiIndex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to know how to pass from a multiindex dataframe like this:

```
A            B
col1   col2  col1   col2
1       2      12     21
3       1       2      0
```

To two separated dfs. df_A:

```
  col1   col2    
   1       2      
   3       1
```

df_B:

```
   col1   col2
    12     21
     2      0
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is better use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for selecting by first level:

```
print (df.xs('A', axis=1, level=0))
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     1
```

What need is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible create DataFrames by groups:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    globals()['df_' + str(i)] =  g.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)

print (df_A)
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     1
```

Better is create dictionary of `DataFrame`s:

```
d = {i:g.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)for i, g in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)}
print (d['A'])
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     1
```