# How can i convert values of iterable to names of variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of `DataFrame` columns name,i want to create some individual `DataFrames` for some specific cases, i want to know  can i use values of `iterable` to names of variables:

**my code:**

```
for label in labels_cols:
    label+"_df" = train_df[train_df[label]== 1]['text_len'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `dict of DataFrames` is better here:

```
dfs = {}
for label in labels_cols:
    dfs[label] = train_df[train_df[label]== 1]['text_len'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Alternative:

```
dfs = {label: train_df[train_df[label]== 1]['text_len'].value_counts().sort_index()
       for label in labels_cols}
```

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible create DataFrames by filtered rows:

```
for label in labels_cols:
    globals()[label+"_df"] = train_df[train_df[label]== 1]['text_len'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Comment: Why 3rd method is not recommended ?

Comment: @Niro - yes, in python. In link is more info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956