# Removing observation with min value in a column out of the dataframe one by one using loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, min

I have a dataframe "data" that looks like this:

| f1 | f2 | f3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 34 | a |
| 14 | 10 | a |
| 20 | 12 | a |
| 15 | 19 | b |
| 19 | 29 | b |
| 29 | 30 | b |

I want to find the minimum value of f2 IF f3 is a. I don't want to find min value of f2 for f3 = a or f3 = b, just when f3 = a. And then I want to remove the observation that is associated with that min value in f2 in the dataframe. So I had this code:

```
a_part = data[data['f3'] == 'a'
min1 = a_part['f2'].min()
min1 = data['f2'] = min1
data_new_1 = pd.dataframe(data.loc[~min1])
```

Which works well. And now my dataframe looks like:

| f1 | f2 | f3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 34 | a |
| 20 | 12 | a |
| 15 | 19 | b |
| 19 | 29 | b |
| 29 | 30 | b |

However, I want to remove the min value of f2 when f3 = a and the associated observation one by one by using a loop, and having a new dataframe each time. So essentially data_new_2 looks like:

| f1 | f2 | f3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 34 | a |
| 15 | 19 | b |
| 19 | 29 | b |
| 29 | 30 | b |

Until there's only b left in f3. I tried to do a loop for it:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    IN = data_new_i[['f3'] == 'a']
    min1 = a_part['f2'].min() 
    min1 = data_new_i['f2'] == min1
    vars()[data_new_i++] = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[~min1])
```

And this doesn't work. I'm very unfamiliar with the way Python treats new dataframe name with loop index. I think I have to use dict to put new dataframe in, but I don't know how I can extract a column of a dataframe from a dict, and how I can save the new dataframe into the dict. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution ouput is list of DataFrames.

If there are always unique values in column `f2` use loop by index values of sorted column and drop row by minimal value:

```
out = []
data1 = data.sort_values('f2')
for i in data1.loc[data1['f3'] == 'a', 'f2'].index:
    data = data.drop(i)
    out.append(data)
print (out)
[   f1  f2 f3
0  11  34  a
2  20  12  a
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b,    f1  f2 f3
0  11  34  a
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b,    f1  f2 f3
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b]
```

If possible duplicates and need remove all dupes, like here in first loop all rows with `f2=10` use:

```
print (data)
   f1  f2 f3
0  11  10  a
1  14  10  a
2  20  12  a
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b

out = []
data1 = data.sort_values('f2')
for i, g in data1.groupby(data1.loc[data1['f3'] == 'a', 'f2']):
    data = data.drop(g.index)
    out.append(data)
print (out)
[   f1  f2 f3
2  20  12  a
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b,    f1  f2 f3
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b]
```

It is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956), but possible create DataFrames by groups:

```
data1 = data.sort_values('f2')
for j, (i, g) in enumerate(data1.groupby(data1.loc[data1['f3'] == 'a', 'f2']), 1):
    data = data.drop(g.index)
    globals()[f'data_new_{j}'] = data
print (data_new_1)
   f1  f2 f3
2  20  12  a
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b

print (data_new_2)
   f1  f2 f3
3  15  19  b
4  19  29  b
5  29  30  b
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I'll try it out soon!

Comment: May I ask what do the i and g represent? Does i represent the location where f3 = a, and g represents each block of unique values of f2?

Comment: @shuu i is here name of group, values used for grouping here 10 and 12 and g is group.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much :)