# python & pandas - Split large dataframe into multiple dataframes and plot diagrams

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, split

I'm under the similar condition with [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes). I'm working on a project which has a large dataframe with about half-million of rows. And about 2000 of users are involving in this.( I get this number by `value_counts()` counting a column called `NoUsager`).

I'd like to split the dataframe into several array/dataframe for plotting after. (Several means an array/dataframe for each user)
I gott the list of users like:

```
df.sort_values(by='NoUsager',inplace=True)
df.set_index(keys=['NoUsager'],drop=False,inplace=True)
users = df['NoUsager'].unique().tolist()
```

I know what's after is a loop to generate the smaller dataframes but I have no idea how to make it happen. And I combined the code above and tried the one in [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes) but there was no solution for it.

What should I do with it?

---

**EDIT**

I want both histogram and boxplot of the dataframe. With the answer provided, I already have a boxplot of all `NoUsager`. But with large amount of data, the boxplot is too small to read. So I'd like to split the dataframe by `NoUsager` and plot them separately.
Diagrams that I'd like to have:

1. boxplot, column=`DureeService`, by=`NoUsager`
2. boxplot, column=`DureeService`, by='Weekday`
3. histogram, for every `Weekday`,by=`DureeService`

I hope this time is well explained.

DataType:

```
          Weekday NoUsager Periods  Sens  DureeService
DataType   string  string  string string datetime.time
```

Sample of DataFrame:

```
Weekday NoUsager Periods Sens DureeService
Lun 000001 Matin + 00:00:05 
Lun 000001 Matin + 00:00:04 
Mer 000001 Matin + 00:00:07 
Dim 000001 Soir  - 00:00:02 
Lun 000001 Matin + 00:00:07 
Jeu 000001 Soir  - 00:00:04 
Lun 000001 Matin + 00:00:07 
Lun 000001 Soir  - 00:00:04 
Dim 000001 Matin + 00:00:05 
Lun 000001 Matin + 00:00:03 
Mer 000001 Matin + 00:00:04 
Ven 000001 Soir  - 00:00:03 
Mar 000001 Matin + 00:00:03 
Lun 000001 Soir  - 00:00:04 
Lun 000001 Matin + 00:00:04 
Mer 000002 Soir  - 00:00:04 
Jeu 000003 Matin + 00:00:50 
Mer 000003 Soir  - 00:06:51 
Mer 000003 Soir  - 00:00:08 
Mer 000003 Soir  - 00:00:10 
Jeu 000003 Matin + 00:12:35 
Lun 000004 Matin + 00:00:05 
Dim 000004 Matin + 00:00:05 
Lun 000004 Matin + 00:00:05 
Lun 000004 Matin + 00:00:05
```

---

And what bothers me is that none of these data is number, so each time they have to be converted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`[g for _, g in df.groupby('NoUsager')]` gives you a list of data frames where each dataframe contains one unique `NoUsager`. But I think what you need is something like:

```
for k, g in df.groupby('NoUsager'):
    g.plot(kind = ..., x = ..., y = ...) etc..
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I updated sth about plotting. what's to do with`k`? Although  `NoUsager` are numeric, but they are saved as `string`. So I should convert them into number before?

Comment: `g` is simply a data frame which contains only one unique `NoUsager` and `k` is the unique `NoUsager` for `g`. You can use it however you want, as title or as label, etc... It's just a number here or you can ignore it if you don't need it. Try a small data frame and `print(g)` using the `for` loop, you will see what I mean.

Comment: @ch36r5s, please provide a sample data set. In this case the SO community will be able to write a working (and tested) snippet for you. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @Psidom Thanks, I have been looking for this all day. You may want to add your explanation to your awnser instead of explaning in the comments though.

Answer (score 1):

No need to sort first. You may try this with your original DataFrame:

```
# import third-party libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Define a function takes the database, and return a dictionary
def splitting_dataframe(df):
    d = {}                                   # Define an empty dictionary
    nousager = np.unique(df.NoUsager.values) # Getting the NoUsage list
    for NU in nousager:                      # Loop over NoUsage list
        d[NU] = df[df.NoUsager == NU]        # I guess this line is what you want most
    return d                                 # Return the dictionary
dictionary = splitting_dataframe(df)  # Calling the function
```

After this, you can call the DataFrame for specific NoUsager by:

```
dictionary[target_NoUsager]
```

Hope this helps.

---

### EDIT

If you want to do a box plot, have you tried:

```
df.boxplot(column='DureeService', by='NoUsager')
```

directly? More information here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html

---

### EDIT

If you want a boxplot for several selected 'NoUsager':

```
targets = [some selected NoUsagers]
mask = np.sum([df.A.values == targets[i] for i in xrange(len(targets))], dtype=bool, axis=0)
df[mask].boxplot(column='DureeService', by='NoUsager')
```

If you want a histogram for a selected 'NoUsager':

```
df[target NoUsager].hist(column='DureeService')
```

If you still need to separate them, @Psidom's first line is good enough.

Comment: it worked for only once, it stopped after the first value of `nousager`.

Comment: as @Psidom suggests, I think "groupby" would be an easier way to go. Still, could you provide the error message?

Comment: I just added a line for boxplot. No need to split the DataFrame if that is what you only need.

Comment: it worked with boxplot. Is it possible to directly plot histogram with this df?

Comment: Indeed, it's not necessarily to split for boxplot. But with this amount of data, the diagram is too small to explain anything statistic.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by 'histogram': do you want have a boxplot for several selected 'NoUsager', or do you want to plot a histogram of 'DureeService' for one 'NoUsager'?

Comment: a histogram of x=`NoUsager`, y= `DureeService`. And `DureeService` as data type `datetime.time()` but not in seconds.

Comment: Hmm...I think we are referring to different kinds of histogram. I added two sets of code above. Hope that helps.