# group DataFrame by column value using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following (pandas) DataFrame:

```
    b    c    d    e
0  100  369  203  314
1  100  228  784  366
2  200  811  664  202
3  200  531  932  575
```

I want to iterate its rows but I need to know where the value of `b` changed.
I am looking for a way to get this DF content in groups or something like that and then iterate over the rows of each group (with a nested loop and in this way I can get an indication that the `b` value did changed):

In the first iteration my new df will be:

```
    b    c    d    e
0  100  369  203  314
1  100  228  784  366
```

In the second iteration my new df will be:

```
    b    c    d    e
0  200  811  664  202
1  200  531  932  575
```

Comment: to clarify: did you want a new df for every single unique value of items in the b column?

Comment: have you looked into groupby?

Comment: I don't really need a new df, if I can get the same result but in other datastructure it will be fine.

Comment: `d={x: y for x, y in df.groupby('b')}
`

Comment: `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('b')))` ?

Comment: Do you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19790790/2901002) ?

Comment: Or new column like `df['new'] = pd.factorize(df['B'])[0]` ?

Comment: Or apply function like `df = df.groupby('b').apply(func)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
columns = ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
data = [[100, 369, 203, 314], [100, 228, 784, 366], [200, 811, 664, 202], [200, 531, 932, 575]]
df = DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)

def split_dfs(df, col):
    return [group[1] for group in list(df.groupby(col))]

dfs = split_dfs(df, "b")

for df_group in dfs:
    print(df_group)
```

> ```
>     b    c    d    e
> 0  100  369  203  314
> 1  100  228  784  366
>      b    c    d    e
> 2  200  811  664  202
> 3  200  531  932  575
> ```