# Return multiple dataframes based on filtering on a looped key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a stream of IP traffic that I need to split and process according to the IP address. I have made a start on the following function:

```
def address_streams(packet_stream):
    addresses = packet_stream.Addr.unique()

    for address in addresses:
      print(address)
      filter = packet_stream[(packet_stream.Addr == address)]
```

How can I return these subset dataframes to be further processed separately?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need processing each group in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def func(subdf):
    print (subdf)
    #add new value
    subdf['new'] = 1
    return subdf

 packet_stream = packet_stream.groupby('Addr').apply(func)
```

EDIT: For loop by each groups use:

```
for name, subdf in packet_stream.groupby('Addr'):
    print (name, subdf)
```

EDIT1: For convert to dictionary of groups use:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Addr')))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful however I would really like to have subsets for each unique IP address if possible?

Comment: Nearly there lol, how do I return the subsets as global variables?

Comment: @Lauren - Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400233/2901002) ?

Comment: yes! but i think i may consider using a dictionary going by these comments [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956/9170329) - thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Lauren - Yes, you can use `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Addr')))` for dictionaries.