# How can i group pandas dataframe based on two colunms?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, analytics

I have a pandas dataframe object in this way:

[image]

I want to create multiple dataframes from it grouped on user and alt_user columns.
Basically, each newly created dataframe should have unique combination of user and alt_user.

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So far I have used  **dataframe1.groupby(['user', 'alt_user'])**
But this does not create multiple dataframes.

Comment: It does create the groups, but these are all stored in the grouped object. What do you want to do with each individual group? As pandas allows you to apply the same operation to each group all at once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting dataframe into multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataframe1.groupby(['user', 'alt_user'])` is not designed to create multiple dataframes, in fact it will not even create one without an aggregation.
To do what you want, you need to start with a list of all unique pairs, which could be gotten in the following way:

```
unique_pairs = set(zip(df.User, df.Alt_user))
```

Then the list of dataframes would be

```
dataframes = [dataframe1.loc[np.logical_and(dataframe1.User==user, dataframe1.Alt_user==alt_user), :] for user, alt_user in unique_pairs]
```

Comment: `[g for _, g in df.groupby(["a", "b"])]` will create a list of subset dataframes.