# Filter one dataframe using another through a loop pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` as two columns with distinct values across multiple rows. It looks similar to the following:

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| aa | 50 |
| bb | 132 |
| dd | 543 |

`df2` has similar structure to the following:

| col_a | col__b | col_x | col_y | col_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | xy | xy | xy | 2 |
| aa | xy | xy | xy | 3 |
| bb | xy | xy | xy | 14 |
| bb | xy | xy | xy | 9 |
| bb | xy | xy | xy | 6 |
| cc | xy | xy | xy | 0 |
| cc | xy | xy | xy | 2 |
| dd | xy | xy | xy | 0 |
| dd | xy | xy | xy | 2 |

I want to filter `df2` through a loop using values from `df1` in a way that after first iteration of loop I end up with the follow:

| col_a | col_b | col_x | col_y | col_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | xy | xy | xy | 2 |
| aa | xy | xy | xy | 3 |

And after second iteration I should have the following:

| col_a | col_b | col_x | col_y | col_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bb | xy | xy | xy | 14 |
| bb | xy | xy | xy | 9 |
| bb | xy | xy | xy | 6 |

I do not want the filtering to modify the `df2` permanently. Subsequent iterations should filter `df2` based on values from col_a of `df1`.

I have no idea how to achieve this so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting dataframe into multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes)

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405971/14289892

Comment: @AnuragDabas not quite because although I want to filter dataframe. I don't split the dataframe. Instead I just want to filter the dataframe temporarily so I can do some arithmetic on its columns then move to second set to values from dataframe2 and do the same again.

Comment: so you want to filter df2 on the basis of col_a of df1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your unique column values, then filter your df2 based on each unique value.  You don't need drop_duplicates if df1 values are unique, but I include it just in case in this toy example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['aa', 'bb']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb'], 'other column':[1, 2, 3, 4]})

for col_value in df1['col_a'].drop_duplicates():
    df_temp_filtered = df2[df2['col_a'] == col_value]
```

to get this df_temp_filtered in round 2:

```
  col_a  other column
2    bb             3
3    bb             4
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and helping me solve this problem. Much appreciated!!