# Dividing pandas dataframe to to separate dataframes by rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
a b c
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

and i need to separate it by rows and create a new dataframe from each row.
i tried to iterate over the rows and then for each row (which is a seriese) i tried the command row.to_df() but it gives me a weird result.

basicly im looking to create bew dataframe sa such:

```
a b c
0 1 2


a b c
3 4 5


a b c
7 8 9
```

Comment: You are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
   new_df = pd.DataFrame(row).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will create a new DataFrame object from each row (Series Object) in the original DataFrame `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate row-by-row and use `.to_frame()`. For example:

```py
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.to_frame().T)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2

   a  b  c
1  3  4  5

   a  b  c
2  6  7  8
```