# Split DataFrame and loop functions over subframes

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':list('12121212'),'NAME':list('aabbccdd'), 'CLASS':list("AAAABBBB"),
               'GRADE':[4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5]}, columns = ['TIME', 'NAME', 'CLASS','GRADE'])
print(df):
  TIME NAME CLASS  GRADE
0    1    a     A      4
1    2    a     A      5
2    1    b     A      4
3    2    b     A      5
4    1    c     B      4
5    2    c     B      5
6    1    d     B      4
7    2    d     B      5
```

What I need to do is split the above dataframe into multiple dataframes according to the variable `CLASS`, convert the dataframe from *long* to *wide* (such that we have `NAMES` as columns and `GRADE` as the main entry in the data matrix) and then iterate other functions over the smaller `CLASS` dataframes. If I create a `dict` object as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes), I obtain:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('CLASS')))
print(d):
{'A':   TIME NAME CLASS  GRADE
0    1    a     A      4
1    2    a     A      5
2    1    b     A      4
3    2    b     A      5, 'B':   TIME NAME CLASS  GRADE
4    1    c     B      4
5    2    c     B      5
6    1    d     B      4
7    2    d     B      5}
```

In order to convert the dataframe from long to wide, I used the function `pivot_table` from `pandas`:

```
for names, classes in d.items():
    newdata=df.pivot_table(index="TIME", columns="NAME", values="GRADE")
print(newdata):
NAME  a  b  c  d
TIME
1     4  4  4  4
2     5  5  5  5
```

So far so good. However, once I obtain the `newdata` dataframe I am not able to access the smaller dataframes created in `d`, since the variable `CLASS` is now missing from the dataframe (as it should be). Suppose I then need to iterate a function over the two smaller subframes `CLASS==A` and `CLASS==B`. How would I be able to do this using a for loop if I am not able to define the dataset structure using the column `CLASS`?

Comment: newdata you are printing outside the for loop, if you indent it and print inside the loop, you should get individual data frames for each class

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `groupby`+`apply` to conserve the group names:

```
(df.groupby('CLASS')
   .apply(lambda d: d.pivot_table(index="TIME", columns="NAME", values="GRADE"))
)
```

output:

```
              a    b    c    d
CLASS TIME                    
A     1     4.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
      2     5.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
B     1     NaN  NaN  4.0  4.0
      2     NaN  NaN  5.0  5.0
```

Other possibility, loop over the groups, keeping CLASS as column:

```
for group_name, group_df in df.groupby('CLASS', as_index=False):
    print(f'working on group {group_name}')
    print(group_df)
```

output:

```
working on group A
  TIME NAME CLASS  GRADE
0    1    a     A      4
1    2    a     A      5
2    1    b     A      4
3    2    b     A      5
working on group B
  TIME NAME CLASS  GRADE
4    1    c     B      4
5    2    c     B      5
6    1    d     B      4
7    2    d     B      5
```

Comment: This seems like I nice solution! How would I be able to loop functions over the subgroups though? And is there a way to retrieve the datasets A and B on their own?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Erickson `apply` enables you to run any function that takes a dataframe as input. Also, check my update for a solution using loops