# How to select all rows with the same name but different values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the pandas DataFarme looks like this:

```
    Name  VALUE
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    A      3
3    B      4
4    B      5
5    C      6
6    C      7
7    C      8
8    C      9
9    D     10
```

I would like to select all the rows with the same name but different values below:

```
    Name  Value
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    A      3


    Name  Value
0    C      6
1    C      7
2    C      8
3    C      9
```

I tried to use .T to transform the rows and columns, and then use .groupby to select all columns with the same name. But, there are two questions: firstly, .groupby can not choose the same columns; secondly, .groupby actually adds all values in one row with the same name, which is not the result I want.

Then, I tried to use .duplicated(keep=False), but this code only tells me if the data is the same or not.

What code should I use? Actually. I have a thousand data and more than 20 of the same name rows as "A", "B", "C", "D", up to "Z". Each name has a thousand different values.

Comment: Do you want different dataframes?

Comment: Yes, I want the different data frames, because I would draw the plot with each name. @AbhyudayVaish

Comment: Try the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71651843/17521785). For your use case, you probably don't need the dict constructor, so just use the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get different dataframes then here's how you can do it:

```
df_splits = [v for k, v in df.groupby('Name')]
for df_split in df_splits:
    print(df_split, sep = '\n')
```

Output:

```
  Name  VALUE
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    A      3
  Name  VALUE
3    B      4
4    B      5
  Name  VALUE
5    C      6
6    C      7
7    C      8
8    C      9
  Name  VALUE
9    D     10
```

To access dataframes individually use:

`df_splits[0]`, `df_splits[1]`....

Comment: @AxiaoNailo Well, you dont cover that in your question. How are you plotting the dataframes? I would suggest you mark the answer and ask another question for plotting

Comment: @AxiaoNailo I would suggest you ask a new question for plotting and reading the docs for [`.hist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html). You can accept the answer if you find it helpful :)