# Split text file with same value

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this

```
Apple TreeTwo
Banana TreeOne
Juice TreeOne
Pineapple TreeThree
Berries TreeThree
```

How can I select the rows with the same Tree name and put them in separate files like below in python

```
file1.txt
Banana TreeOne
Juice TreeOne

file2.txt
Apple TreeTwo

file3.txt
Pineapple
Berries
```

I've tried using this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72065988/how-to-select-all-rows-with-the-same-name-but-different-values-in-python" but getting no attribute groupby error. My column don't have headers, so don't know if this is how to do it or is there another way?

```
f = open('data.txt' , 'r')
f_splits = [v for k, v in f.groupby()]
for f_split in f_splits:
    print(f_split, sep = '\n')
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying, so we can see why you get the error you mention?

Comment: I've updated above

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't actually use groupby here, simply iterating over the file contents and then separating it into lists is easier.

Note that you could optimize this into a single for loop, but I'm not, to make it more understandable...

I'm using a dict in my example below as it is able to deal with unknown values easily.

```py
data = """Apple TreeTwo
Banana TreeOne
Juice TreeOne
Pineapple TreeThree
Berries TreeThree"""

result = {}
for line in data.splitlines():
    # get the last word to determine which list to put it in
    sort_key = line.split()[-1]
    # remove the last word, by splitting and rejoining.
    line = " ".join(line.split()[:-1])
    if sort_key not in result:
        # if the key is not already in the dict, create a new list with 
        # line as the first element
        result[sort_key] = [line]
    else:
        # if the key is already there, append line to the list
        result[sort_key].append(line)

#print it out
for key, value in result.items():
    print(f"{key} → {value}")


# write to files
for key, value in result.items():
    with open(f"{key}.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in value:
            outfile.write(f"{line}\n")
```

**output**

```
TreeTwo → ['Apple']
TreeOne → ['Banana', 'Juice']
TreeThree → ['Pineapple', 'Berries']
```

Comment: Is there a way I can outfile.write only the value ie ['Apple'] ['Banana Juice] without the Treename?

Comment: yes, I've written the full line as that was what you put in the example. If the last word is the only one you want to remove, it's a simple adjustment. See my updated answer, which basically removes the last word from each line

Comment: note that if the lines always only have 2 words, you can simplify the two lines that define `sort_key` and `line` using the splits, with the following: `line, sort_key = line.split()`