# Sorting all records based on the group of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataset like this:

```
user_id     record_time               accu       lat       lon        bin-lat  bin-lon
0   1335    2017-02-28 18:11:00     21.581  52.130910   -106.639214      207    185     
1   1335    2017-02-28 18:17:00     21.205  52.130910   -106.639214      208    183     
2   1335    2017-02-28 18:22:00     21.998  52.131086   -106.638881      207    185     
3   1335    2017-02-28 18:25:00     28.000  52.130828   -106.637958      209    184     
4   1335    2017-02-28 18:25:00     7.000   52.130806   -106.637825      208    183     
5   1335    2017-02-28 18:25:00     6.000   52.130799   -106.637810      209    184
```

I want to sort the whole dataset based on the group of two columns of ('bin-lat' & 'bin-lon'). How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using Pandas here? If so, please add that to the question.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Pandas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put it into a pandas dataframe you can do a simple sort by columns:

```
import pandas as pd

your_table = pd.DataFrame(put_your_table_array_here)

sorted_table = your_table.sort_values(by=['bin-lat', 'bin-lon'], ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> student_objects = [
...     Student('john', 'A', 15),
...     Student('jane', 'B', 12),
...     Student('dave', 'B', 10),
... ]
>>> s = sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('age'))     # sort on secondary key
>>> sorted(s, key=attrgetter('grade'), reverse=True)       # now sort on primary key, descending
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts

Comment: This has ZERO to do with pandas.