# Sorting a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with columns ['name', 'sex', 'births', 'year']. I then group the dataframe on the basis of name to create 2 new columns "max" and "total".

```
trendy_names['max'] = trendy_names.groupby(['name'], as_index = False)['births'].transform('max')
trendy_names['total'] = trendy_names.groupby(['name'], as_index = False)['births'].transform('sum')
```

Using these 2 columns, I create a calculated column "trendiness".

```
trendy_names['trendiness'] = trendy_names['max']/trendy_names['total']
```

Then, I segregate those that have a total number of births greater than 1000.

```
trendy_names = trendy_names[trendy_names.total >= 1000]
```

Now, I want to sort the dataframe on the basis of "trendiness" column. Any thoughts?

Comment: name sex  births  year    max    total  trendiness
0       Mary   F    7065  1880  73983  4135851    0.017888
1       Anna   F    2604  1880  15666   886614    0.017669
2       Emma   F    2003  1880  22702   635686    0.035713
3  Elizabeth   F    1939  1880  20742  1625783    0.012758
4     Minnie   F    1746  1880   3274   159494    0.020527

Comment: That's *too much* information (yes, that's a thing). This whole question really boils down to "how to sort a (grouped) dataframe based on values in a specific column"

Comment: @jezrael
That's exactly what I want. But I cant do it as the dataframe is already grouped by.

Comment: @Tanmoy - Then need `trendy_names = rendy_names.sort_values(['name','trendiness'])`

Comment: Also check - [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17141558)

Comment: @jezrael - This doesn't work. The code snippet would sort on the basis of name and trendiness. What I want, instead, is to group on the basis of name and sort on the basis of trendiness. Thoughts?

Comment: @Tanmoy - It is not same? I think yes. Can you add sme snippet of data?

Comment: @jezrael
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RYjjBJ33w3FvYb-LWNrRIieAtl4O8Bcq
Here's the snippet. Till I put in the condition, the df is fine. But as soon as I do, it gets messy. Thoughts?

Comment: @Tanmoy - I check it and I am confused. What is expected output? I think the best is working here with small data sample - 10-20 rows, test solution and if working (in small data sample easy verifyable) apply solution to all dataset.Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael
As you could see in the dataframe.head(), it shows grouped "name". But the moment I use the filter condition df[df.column >=1000].sort_values(by=[col2'], ascending=False).... this ungroups the data.

Comment: Do you try `df[df.column >=1000].sort_values(by=['name', 'col2'], ascending=[True, False])` ?

Answer (score 0):

To sort the dataframe on the basis of "trendiness" which is type: DataFrameGroupBy

```
 1. trendy_names.reset_index()
```

`reset_index()` - converting back to a regular index
        i.e converting pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy to        pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
 2. trendy_names.sort_values(by = 'trendiness')
```