# Order number per sub group in Pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I my trying to create a order to the following dataset, on email sent to each individual

[Current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQMi8.png)
and make it look like (send_num added) the following

[Expected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V83M.png)

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this, many thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: But it seems need [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17141558)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
d["sent_num"] = d.groupby("email").cumcount() + 1
```