# How to sort Table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting

Hello I would like to sort the Bundesliga table according to the points of each team not by the team name. Can someone help me? Currently I can sort the issue only by team name. I don't know how to sort the points after the for-loop.

```
def push2(self):
    #Download Database
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(
        "http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1819/d1.csv",
        "2018-19.csv")
    #Read Database
    df = pd.read_csv("2018-19.csv")
    teams = df["HomeTeam"]
    teams = teams.drop_duplicates()
    teams = teams.sort_values(0, False, False)
    teams = teams.tolist()
    namesLen = len(teams)
    for i in range(0, namesLen):


        # Get points through victories
        team = df[(df["HomeTeam"] == teams[i]) | (
                df["AwayTeam"] == teams[i])]
        teamWin = team[((team["FTR"] == "H") & (
                team["HomeTeam"] == teams[i])) | (
                               (team["FTR"] == "A") & (
                               team["AwayTeam"] == teams[
                           i]))]
        teamTotalPoints = (len(teamWin.index) * 3)

        # Get points through draw
        teamU = df[(df["HomeTeam"] == teams[i]) | (
                df["AwayTeam"] == teams[i])]
        teamD = teamU[(team["FTR"] == "D")]
        teamDTotal = (len(teamD.index) * 1)

        # Total points wins and points draws
        teamT = teamTotalPoints + teamDTotal

        teamTStr = str(teamT)


        print(str( teamTStr + ": " +teams[i] ))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Comment: I really can't follow what this code is doing. Why do you have `df = pd.read_csv("2018-19.csv")` inside a `for` loop?

Comment: I want to sort the print line by points

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a closer look into the Pandas Documentation, particularly the `groupby` (link [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)) and `merge` (link [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)) functions. They give great examples that offer pieces of the answer that you are looking for. For more examples on what merge can offer, take a look at [this article](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/) with tons of examples on the different combinations.

That being said, below is a way to use just Pandas to yield the total goals in order from highest to lowest for clubs in this league.

Some assumptions I took:

- The Python version used is 2.7
- The Pandas version used is at least 0.19.
- After doing some grouping and sorting, the end result is a new `dataframe` which can be manipulated.
- The file is already loaded into your python script.
- The columns are based off of http://www.football-data.co.uk/notes.txt
- Assumes no errors in the `HomeTeam` column.

The function below should be repeatable as long as your dataframe follows the same structure as the link you listed.

```
import pandas as pd

def sortTable(df):
    """
    Returns a pd.DataFrame with goals scored by teams, sorted by total goals.

    df: pd.DataFrame, raw dataframe taken from .csv.
    """
    # groups by the Home team name, sums the FTHG, resets the grouping object indexing
    home_goals = df.groupby(['HomeTeam'])[['FTHG']].sum().reset_index()

    # rename the HomeTeam column to 'Team', column shared by tables to be merged
    home_goals.rename(columns = {'HomeTeam': 'Team'}, inplace = True)

    # groups by the away team name, sums the FTAG, resets the grouping object indexing
    away_goals = df.groupby(['AwayTeam'])[['FTAG']].sum().reset_index()
    away_goals.rename(columns = {'AwayTeam': 'Team'}, inplace = True)

    # merge the 2 tables by the team name
    goals_table = pd.merge(home_goals, away_goals, on='Team')
    goals_table['FTG'] = goals_table['FTHG'] + goals_table['FTAG']

    return goals_table.sort_values('FTG', ascending=False)


""" ------ Run Function Example ------ """
df_old = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv')
df_new = sortTable(df_old)
```