# How Do I get Pandas to sort zeros to beginning of indexing?

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DF(dataframe) that was created by taking a list of DF's with concat as such:

```
conc_list = pandas.concat(DF_list, keys=range(len(DF_list)), names= ['one','for_date_time_object'], sort= True)
```

but it puts the zeros at the end of the dataframe.

```
  
for_date_time_object  one
2018-09-26 05:30:00   1      1537939800
                      2      1537939800
                      3      1537939800
2018-09-26 05:35:00   1      1537940100
2018-09-26 05:40:00   1      1537940400
2018-09-26 05:45:00   1      1537940700
                      2      1537940700
2018-09-26 05:50:00   1      1537941000
2018-09-26 05:55:00   1      1537941300
2018-09-26 06:00:00   1      1537941600

2018-11-07 05:30:00   0      1541595900
2018-11-07 05:31:00   0      1541595960
2018-11-07 05:32:00   0      1541596020
2018-11-07 05:33:00   0      1541596080
2018-11-07 05:34:00   0      1541596140
```

how can I get it to sort from 0-9?

```
for_date_time_object  one
2018-09-26 05:30:00   0      1537939800
                      1      1537939800
                      2      1537939800
                      3      1537939800
2018-11-07 05:31:00   0      1541595960
2018-11-07 05:32:00   0      1541596020
2018-11-07 05:33:00   0      1541596080
2018-11-07 05:34:00   0      1541596140
2018-09-26 05:35:00   0      1537940100
2018-09-26 05:35:00   1      1537940100
2018-11-07 05:36:00   0      1541595960
2018-11-07 05:37:00   0      1541596020
2018-11-07 05:38:00   0      1541596080
2018-11-07 05:39:00   0      1541596140
2018-09-26 05:40:00   0      1537940400
2018-09-26 05:40:00   1      1537940400
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the look, along with Zanshin and Alok Shrestha for the answers.  Upon recreating the problem with some random generated data I found that I had not equated my variable to the new instance earlier in my code, and that lead to the problem I was having.

Comment: if the answers were helpful you might accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try this :

```
conc_list.sort_values('one')
```

Comment: An explanation would make this answer helpful to a great many more people.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a column name for the third column, you can try multi level sort with sorting by third column then by second column (one).
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141755/3544368

Comment: I tried that but it didn't solve the issue for me of zero's in the 'one' column getting dumped at the end of the DF.