# Sort dataframe by timestamp in two separated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data with timestamp (date and time are in two separated columns)

`id,    device,action, day,         time 
 658,   FD,    1,      02-Mar-2008, 19:37:41
 659,   FD,    0,      02-Mar-2008, 19:37:46
 660,   HTD,   1,      02-Mar-2008, 20:32:17
 661,   HTD,   0,      02-Mar-2008, 20:32:18
 662,   HTD,   1,      02-Mar-2008, 20:32:22`

How can I sort may data by timestamp like it is in one column ?

`df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.sort_values('timestamp')`

Note: I am dealing with timestamp not textual columns as in this question [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns).

I tried the code in that answer and it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Actually, you should do `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'] + ' ' + df['time'])` and do `sort_values`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to create a new column

Comment: You can simply do `df.sort_values(pd.to_datetime(df['day'] + ' ' + df['time'])`.