# How to sort multilevel index on column values

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, multi-level

I'm trying to sort data in a multilevel index for visualisation.
At this point it is purely to order the data based on the values

I've tried working with sort_index and sort_values, however neither have worked.
I'm assuming there is a way to combine the 2 that is not clear to me.

#### Example code

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'lev1':[1,1,2,2], 
        'lev2':['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item2'], 
        'col1':[.55, .44, .22, .34],
        'col2':[.54, .86, .55, .44]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.set_index(['lev1', 'lev2'], inplace=True)
```

#### This should result in :

```
                col1    col2
    lev1 lev2       
    1   item1   0.55    0.54
        item2   0.44    0.86
    2   item3   0.22    0.55
        item2   0.34    0.44
```

What I would like to see is the output ordered based on the values in col2. However, keeping the multilevel index intact.

#### Meaning, the results should show:

```
                col1    col2
    lev1 lev2       
    1   item2   0.44    0.86
        item1   0.55    0.54
    2   item3   0.22    0.55
        item2   0.34    0.44
```

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Answer (score 5):

For **pandas 0.23+** is possible sorting by index and by columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['lev1','col2'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
            col1  col2
lev1 lev2             
1    item2  0.44  0.86
     item1  0.55  0.54
2    item3  0.22  0.55
     item2  0.34  0.44
```

For lower versions of pandas is necessary [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), sorting and then [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .sort_values(['lev1','col2'], ascending=[True, False])
        .set_index(['lev1','lev2']))
```