# Grouping by a column based on the minimum year value returned from the max value of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Apologies for the confusing title. It is explained better below. 
I currently have a pandas data frame that looks something like this:

```
user_id year grade_id
1       2005 47
1       2003 70
1       2004 70
2       2011 50
2       2003 43
2       2009 60
```

I want to group by the user_id and return the minimum year value based on the max value of grade_id. So the output for the above data frame would look like so:

```
user_id year grade_id
1       2003 70
2       2009 60
```

Is there a simple/elegant way to do this? I have tried things like the following:

```py
tmp_df = df.groupby(["user_id", "year"])["grade_id"].agg(np.max)
```

However, this does not return the correct year. I have already checked out a few StackOverflow posts but none seem to be the same issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `ascent_year`?

Comment: That should be "year". Changed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will work well on large data frames.

```py
df.sort_values('grade_id', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['user_id'])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not work for all cases, the default option for `keep` in `drop_duplicates` is `first`. If by any chance, the `grade_id` has two years, and the first one is not the minimum, then it will fail to work.

Comment: Good point, I checked to see if sort_values can sort by two columns and it can, so I used this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141755/9111394

Answer (score 1):

Given the information this should work for you! I couldn't find an 'easy' way to solve it, but this generates the expected output!

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'user_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'year':[2005,2003,2004,2011,2003,2009],'grade_id':[47,70,70,50,43,60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
final_df = df.groupby('user_id').agg({'grade_id':'max'}).reset_index().merge(df[['grade_id','year']],how='left').sort_values('year').drop_duplicates('user_id')
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
   user_id  grade_id  year
0        1        70  2003
2        2        60  2009
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work with your example

```py
df.groupby(['user_id', 'year']).grade_id.max().groupby(level=0).head(1).reset_index(name='grade_id')
```