# Sorting on two columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (this is a sample there are many rows)

```
      Student ID        avg
0       205842      68.333333
1       280642      74.166667
```

I want to sort by decreasing average percentage grade, and, if equal the Increasing Student ID.

I have been able to sort with one parameter like below, however I'm unsure how to sort with two as I want

```
df_pct_scores.sort_values(by='avg', ascending=False)
```

Comment: `df_pct_scores.sort_values(by=['avg','ID'], ascending=False)` please try this

Comment: Thanks for your input, however - aren't both of these sorting by descending? The second value 'ID' I want to be ascending

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this works:

```
df_pct_scores.sort_values(by = ['avg','ID'], ascending=[False, True])
```