# Sorting across multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Alpha", 3, 2, 4], ["Bravo", 2, 3, 1], ["Charlie", 4, 1, 3], ["Delta", 1, 4, 2]], 
              columns = ["Company", "Running", "Combat", "Range"])
print(df)
  Company Running   Combat  Range
0   Alpha      3      2       4
1   Bravo      2      3       1
2   Charlie    4      1       3
3   Delta      1      4       2
```

Hi, I am trying to sort the the following dataframe so the rows would be arranged such that the best performing across the three columns would be at the top. In this case would be Bravo company as it is 2 in running, 3 in drills and 1 in range.

Would this approach work if the list have a lot more companies and it is hard to know the exact "best performing company"?

I have tried:

```
df_sort = df.sort_values(['Running', 'Combat', 'Range'], ascending=[True, True, True])
```

current output:

```
    Company Running Combat  Range
1   Delta      1      4     2
0   Bravo      2      3     1
3   Alpha      3      2     4
2   Charlie    4      1     3
```

but it doesn't turn out how I wanted it to be. Can this be done through pandas? 
I was expecting the output to be:

```
Company Running Combat  Range
0   Bravo   2     3     1
1   Delta   1     4     2
2   Charlie 4     1     3
3   Alpha   3     2     4
```

Comment: Can you please share your expected output?

Comment: is row 0 the list of companies? if so, how is charlie 2 in running? which column is drills?

Comment: your dataframe structure looks weird to me. is that what is actually is? Can you correct the dataframe structure if not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Comment: Yes I would inspect your `df`with `df.head()`, I don't think the data are being represented how you think

Comment: So you need `df_sort = df.sort_values('Range')` ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Hi, so sorry for the wrong dataframe example. I was trying to sort this through excel but I couldn't copy paste from the excel table. I have updated the question and current & expected output to make the question clearer.

Comment: @jezrael Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to sort according to the "best average performance" across the three columns. It can be manually sorted according to "range" column now as there is only 4 rows, but there are thousands of rows more and would not be feasible to manually observe and sort the rows. Not sure if my question is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want sorting by `mean`s per rows first create `mean`, then add [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values and last change order of values by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[df.mean(axis=1).argsort()]
print (df1)
   Company  Running  Combat  Range
1    Bravo        2       3      1
3    Delta        1       4      2
2  Charlie        4       1      3
0    Alpha        3       2      4
```

EDIT: If need remove some columns before by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
cols = ['Overall','Subordination']
df2 = text_df.iloc[text_df.drop(cols, axis=1).mean(axis=1).argsort()]
print (df2)
   Company  Running  Combat  Overall Subordination  Range
1    Bravo        2       3     0.70          Poor      1
3    Delta        1       4     0.83          Good      2
2  Charlie        4       1     0.81          Good      3
0    Alpha        3       2     0.91     Excellent      4
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand the line of code. Does it mean df.mean(axis=1) will calculate the mean of all the columns before using .argsort() to move the rows according to the mean values?

Comment: @MooseCakeRunner - exactly you are right. I understand question need sorting by mean, or I am wrong?

Comment: Yes that is correct, think my initial wasn't clear. This method of sorting works if there are more columns of ranking and more rows of companies (i.e. hundreds/thousands more)? I do not need to manually name the columns and rows to be sorted?

Comment: @MooseCakeRunner - Sure, if need mean per rows number of columns is not important.

Comment: how about if there are other columns in between the columns which are like text strings, how would I go about that situation then?

Comment: @MooseCakeRunner - For me `mean` omit this columns, if not working use `df.select_dtypes(np.number).mean(axis=1).argsort()` for only numeric columns

Comment: Certainly did helped, but is it possible to "drop" the columns, sort it by mean then place the columns dropped back after sorting in the same manner?

Comment: @MooseCakeRunner - It worked like `text_df.drop(cols, axis=1).mean(axis=1).argsort()` returned positions of rows, so if seelct by `iloc` get original data with changed order.

Comment: Hi, just to clear things up. So text_df.drop(cols, axis=1) will drop the columns not needed for sorting; mean(axis=1).argsort() will calculate the mean before sorting the rows; iloc will move the original data according to the sorted rows by mean without affecting the columns arrangement?