# Reverse sort_values() on columns of string type

Tags: python, pandas

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns) discussed using `sort_values` to sort data frame by column.

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) discussed how to concisely reverse a string, using slicing.

My problem: I want to sort a data frame using a column whose values are string, like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a1a', 'a3d', 'a2b',  'a4c'], columns=['col'])
```

`sort_value()` sorts string character from left to right. In this case, the output is:

```
df_sort = df.sort_values(['col'])

   col
0  a1a
1  a2b
2  a3d
3  a4c
```

If I want to sort character from right to left, what is the best way to combine the `sort_values()` and reverse string syntax to achieve this efficiently?
Expected output (note the switched order of item index 2 and 3)

```
   col
0  a1a
1  a2b
2  a4c
3  a3d
```

Update: Expected output from @Anurag Dabas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a1a', 'a2b', 'a3d', 'a4c','b9a','c8b'], columns=['col'])

df_sort = 


0  a1a
1  b9a
2  a2b
3  c8b
4  a4c
5  a3d
```

Comment: how this is sorted  `df = pd.DataFrame(['a1a', 'a2b', 'a3d', 'a4c','b9a','c8b'], columns=['col'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `key` parameter in `sort_values()`:

```
df_sort =df.sort_values(['col'],key=lambda x:x.str[-1],ignore_index=True)
```

output of `df_sort`:

```
    col
0   a1a
1   b9a
2   a2b
3   c8b
4   a4c
5   a3d
```

Comment: It can be done by Simply use ascending=False... right?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar No because OP wants to sort on the basis of last variable of Series

Comment: @Abhishekkumar ```sort_values()``` look at the first left character, compare those. If they are the same, then it looks at the second char from left, and compare those (ascending or descending, same process). I am looking to do this from right to left, instead. They don't the same result.

Answer (score 2):

So you have to basically reverse the column and then sort it.

You can do this with `pd.DataFrame.apply` and then `pd.DataFrame.sort_values`:

```
df.loc[df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1]).sort_values().index]

   col
0  a1a
1  a2b
3  a4c
2  a3d
```

Or just using the `key` parameter in `pd.DataFrame.sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values(['col'], key=lambda x: x.str[::-1])

   col
0  a1a
1  a2b
3  a4c
2  a3d
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. Yours similar to @Anurag Dabas. Since I saw his response first, I am going to with his.