# How to sort a Pandas DataFrame by multiple columns in Python with ordered number

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe which has 3 columns.

| Code | Volume | Trade Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 500 | 1000 |
| Amazon | 1000 | 500 |
| Facebook | 250 | 750 |
| Samsung | 100 | 1500 |

Firstly, I want to sort volume columns ascending: False that means largest to smallest. Afterwards, making new column which name is "Volume Order" and giving number as a sorting number. Secondly, I want to sort Trade Value ascending: False that means largest to smallest. Afterwards, making new column which name is "Trade Order" and giving number as a sorting number. But, when I sort Trade value, Sorted volume column order is changing according to trade volume order. Finally, I have 2 sorted columns and 2 ordered columns. Lastly, I want to sort and create a new and final column by taking the maximum of 2 separate columns sorted.(Volume Order- Trade Order).

Expected output(when volume and trade value sorting in order:

| Code | Volume Order | Trade Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Samsung | 4 | 1 |
| Apple | 2 | 2 |
| Facebook | 3 | 3 |
| Amazon | 1 | 4 |

Final output:

| Code | Max Ordered Number | Final Sorted Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Samsung | 4 | 1 |
| Amazon | 4 | 2 |
| Facebook | 3 | 3 |
| Apple | 2 | 4 |

Note: if they are the same max ordered number, the trade value will be the more important, which will be expressed by the finale of the larger one. Example; samsung 4-4. But samsung has biggest trade order. That's why it is the larger one as final sorted numbers.

When I try this code; I can't make it. Can you help this issue?

```py
ordered = volume_df.sort_values(by=['Volume'], ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
ordered['Volume Order'] = ordered.index+1 
ordered = trade_value_df.sort_values(by=['Trade Value'], ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
ordered['Trade Order'] = ordered.index+1
```

Comment: Great effort at a first question! But can you provide a minimal example to help us reproduce the code? So we don't have to create the dataframe ourselves

Comment: Thank you. my dataframe is located above. İf you reproduce the code to this example, I can use it. I need really help

Comment: What does *"When I try this code; I can't make it"* mean?

Comment: You can add some code to show us how you create `volume_df` and `trade_value_df` :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Comment: Note that when you write `ordered = trade_value_df.sort_values(by=['Trade Value'], ascending=False,ignore_index=True)`, you are assigning something new to the name `ordered`, so you're effectively losing the dataframe you had previously assigned to that name.

Comment: exactly. the previous order disappears and only trade value order remains. Can you help me

Comment: Here is the dataframe for the question. `pd.DataFrame({'Code' : ['Apple', 'Amazon', 'Facebook', 'Samsung'],'Volume' : [500, 1000, 250, 100],'Trade Value' : [1000, 500, 750, 1500]})`

Comment: @Bianconera In the future it's better if you can provide a minimum example so that we don't have to rewrite the dataset ourselves; see for instance [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue when you write:

```py
ordered = trade_value_df.sort_values(by=['Trade Value'], ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
```

You are assigning something new to the name `ordered`, so you're effectively losing the dataframe you had previously assigned to that name.

A possibility is to do all the operations on the same dataframe, rather than have multiple dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['Apple', 'Amazon', 'Facebook', 'Samsung'], 'Volume':[500, 1000, 250, 100], 'Trade Value': [1000, 500, 750, 1500]})

df = df.sort_values(by=['Volume'], ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
df['Volume Order'] = df.index + 1

df = df.sort_values(by=['Trade Value'], ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
df['Trade Order'] = df.index + 1

print(df)
#        Code  Volume  Trade Value  Volume Order  Trade Order
# 0   Samsung     100         1500             4            1
# 1     Apple     500         1000             2            2
# 2  Facebook     250          750             3            3
# 3    Amazon    1000          500             1            4
```

Comment: what a great answer.  I made it.  Finally, can you produce code Max Ordered Number  and Final Sorted Number according to located above example

Comment: @Bianconera mozway's suggestion to use `rank` instead of `sort_values().index` is better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `sort_values` and index use `rank`:

```py
df['Volume Order'] = df['Volume'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Trade Order']  = df['Trade'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Trade Order2']  = df['Trade'].rank(ascending=True)
df['Max Ordered Number']  = df[['Volume Order', 'Trade Order']].max(axis=1)
df['Final Sorted Number'] = df[['Max Ordered Number', 'Trade Order2']].apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(ascending=False)
df.drop('Trade Order2', axis=1)
```

output:

```
       Code  Volume  Trade  Value  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number
0     Apple     500   1000   <NA>             2            2                   2                    4
1    Amazon    1000    500   <NA>             1            4                   4                    2
2  Facebook     250    750   <NA>             3            3                   3                    3
3   Samsung     100   1500   <NA>             4            1                   4                    1
```

Comment: @Bianconera I use a temporary 'Trade Order2' column that is sorted in the same expected order as 'Max Ordered Number'

Comment: Yes, it will, this is sorting on the first key and then on the second in case of a tie

Comment: @Bianconera maybe open a new question, it is difficult to do follow-ups as comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375616/how-can-i-sort-number-that-according-to-this-order-the-codes-will-take-shapepa  can you help me ?