# How can I construct double sorted portfolio?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, portfolio

[image]

My code of decile portfolio by RETl1 and VOL

```
merged['decile_RETl1'] = merged.groupby(['Date'])['RET_l1'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, duplicates='drop',labels=False))

merged['decile_RETl1']=merged['decile_RETl1']+1

merged['decile_turnover'] = merged.groupby(['Date'])['VOL'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, duplicates='drop',labels=False))

merged['decile_turnover']=merged['decile_turnover']+1
```

I'm able to create a decile portfolio by RETl1 and VOL each
but I don't know how to create conditional decile sorts portfolio by
**first on RETl1 and then on VOL within RETl1 deciles.**

Please answer me if you know how to create
conditional decile sorts portfolio.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For better answers, it would be helpful if you present an example for the desired output for a small sample of data.
The original data is not critical, share a small sample to demonstrate the dataframe structure and the output that you need. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in sorting a Pandas DataFrame by multiple columns, as I understand from your question, you can use [`sort_values`](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) method.

For example:

```py
merged = merged.sort_values(["RETl1", "VOL"], ascending = (True, True))
```

More relevant insight in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns).