# I want to sort my pandas dataframe using two different columns

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a csv data that contains soccer predictions. I sorted it using `sort_values(by=["total_predicted_goals"]`. My problem now is to let the dates be sorted by descending or ascending order.[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMvHQ.jpg)
**view.py**

```
def over_goals(request):
    df = pd.read_csv("media/csv/predictions_with_gridsearch.csv")
    df = df[
        ['match_datetime', 'country', 'league', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds','predicted_home_score', 'predicted_away_score']
        ]
    df['total_predicted_goals'] = df['predicted_home_score'] + df['predicted_away_score']
    df = df.set_axis(['Match_Datetime', 'Country', 'League', 'Home_team', 'Away_team','home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds','Predicted_home_score', 'Predicted_away_score', 'total_predicted_goals'], axis=1)
    df1 = df.sort_values(by=["total_predicted_goals"], ascending=False)
    df1 = df1.drop(['home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds'], axis=1)
    
    df1 = df1.head(10)
    dt = ['Over 2.5', 'Over 2.5', 'Over 2.5', 'Over 2.5', 'Over 2.5', 'Over 1.5', 'Over 1.5','Over 1.5','Over 1.5','Over 1.5']
    df1['Prediction'] = dt
    df2 = df1.drop(['Predicted_home_score', 'Predicted_away_score', 'total_predicted_goals'], axis=1)
    df2 = df2.style
    goals = df2.to_html()  
    return render(request, 'over_goals.html', {
        'goals': goals
        })`][2]
```

Comment: sort_values(by=["total_predicted_goals", "dates"])

Comment: I tried this - df1 = df.sort_values(by=["total_predicted_goals", "Match_Datetime"], ascending=False) but the output still remains same

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by multiple columns with different orders:

For instance:

```
df = df.sort_values(['total_predicted_goals', 'dates'], ascending=[False, True])
```

Comment: sorry, seems no research for dupes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns can you convert to wiki?