# Sorting the bouding box

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, bounding-box

I have a data frame with columns left, top, width, and height. How do I sort the products on the basis of bounding boxes from left to right and top to bottom?

Comment: you can see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)